# Ubuntu 14.04 Failed to load module udlfb

Tags: 14.04, displaylink

DisplayLink doesn't load and run.

The adapter is recognized and /dev/FB1 is created.
USB bus info: Bus 001 Device 006: ID 17e9:0198 DisplayLink

Xorg.0.log:

```
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
[ 44708.386] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[ 44708.389] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-37-generic i686 Ubuntu
[ 44708.392] Current Operating System: Linux rrl 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:08:14 UTC 2014 i686
[ 44708.392] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=6b719a77-29e0-4668-8f16-57d0d3a73a3f ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[ 44708.399] Build Date: 16 April 2014  01:40:08PM
[ 44708.402] xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[ 44708.405] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[ 44708.412]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
  to make sure that you have the latest version.
[ 44708.412] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
  (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
  (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 44708.427] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu May  1 09:38:27 2014
[ 44708.431] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[ 44708.434] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 44708.435] (==) ServerLayout "X.org Configured"
[ 44708.435] (**) |-->Screen "DisplayLinkScreen" (0)
[ 44708.435] (**) |   |-->Monitor "DisplayLinkMonitor"
[ 44708.435] (**) |   |-->Device "DisplayLinkDevice"
[ 44708.435] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (1)
[ 44708.435] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[ 44708.435] (**) |   |-->Device "Card0"
[ 44708.435] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[ 44708.435] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[ 44708.435] (==) Automatically adding devices
[ 44708.435] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[ 44708.435] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[ 44708.435] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[ 44708.435]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 44708.435] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[ 44708.435]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 44708.435] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[ 44708.435]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 44708.435] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[ 44708.435]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 44708.435] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[ 44708.435]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 44708.435] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[ 44708.435]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 44708.435] (**) FontPath set to:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
  built-ins,
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
  built-ins
[ 44708.435] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[ 44708.435] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[ 44708.435] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[ 44708.435] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[ 44708.435] (II) Loader magic: 0xb77106c0
[ 44708.435] (II) Module ABI versions:
[ 44708.435]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[ 44708.435]    X.Org Video Driver: 15.0
[ 44708.435]    X.Org XInput driver : 20.0
[ 44708.435]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[ 44708.436] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[ 44708.436] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[ 44708.437] (--) PCI:*(0:1:5:0) 1002:9616:105b:0e26 rev 0, Mem @ 0xf0000000/134217728, 0xfeae0000/65536, 0xfe900000/1048576, I/O @ 0x0000b000/256
[ 44708.441] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[ 44708.444] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[ 44708.448] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[ 44708.452] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[ 44708.456] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[ 44708.460] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[ 44708.464] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[ 44708.468] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[ 44708.471] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[ 44708.475] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[ 44708.479] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[ 44708.483] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[ 44708.487] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[ 44708.491] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[ 44708.494] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[ 44708.498] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[ 44708.502] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[ 44708.506] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[ 44708.510] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[ 44708.513] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[ 44708.517] Initializing built-in extension Present
[ 44708.521] Initializing built-in extension DRI3
[ 44708.525] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[ 44708.528] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[ 44708.532] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[ 44708.535] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[ 44708.539] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[ 44708.542] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[ 44708.546] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[ 44708.549] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[ 44708.549] (II) "glx" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
[ 44708.549] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[ 44708.549] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[ 44708.549] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[ 44708.550] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 44708.550]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[ 44708.550]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 8.0
[ 44708.550] (==) AIGLX enabled
[ 44708.553] Loading extension GLX
[ 44708.553] (II) LoadModule: "udlfb"
[ 44708.554] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module udlfb
[ 44708.554] (II) UnloadModule: "udlfb"
[ 44708.554] (II) Unloading udlfb
[ 44708.554] (EE) Failed to load module "udlfb" (module does not exist, 0)
[ 44708.554] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[ 44708.554] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[ 44708.554] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 44708.554]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[ 44708.554]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 44708.554]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[ 44708.554] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 0
[ 44708.554] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 1
[ 44708.554] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 2
[ 44708.554] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 3
[ 44708.554] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 4
[ 44708.554] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 5
[ 44708.554] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 6
[ 44708.554] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[ 44708.554] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[ 44708.554] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fglrx
[ 44708.554] (II) UnloadModule: "fglrx"
[ 44708.554] (II) Unloading fglrx
[ 44708.554] (EE) Failed to load module "fglrx" (module does not exist, 0)
[ 44708.554] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[ 44708.554] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[ 44708.554] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 44708.554]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 7.3.0
[ 44708.554]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 44708.554]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[ 44708.554] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"
[ 44708.555] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
[ 44708.555] (II) Module radeon: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 44708.555]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 7.3.0
[ 44708.555]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 44708.555]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[ 44708.555] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[ 44708.555] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[ 44708.555] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 44708.555]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.8.1
[ 44708.555]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 44708.555]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[ 44708.555] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[ 44708.555] (II) Unloading modesetting
[ 44708.555] (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 0)
[ 44708.555] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[ 44708.555] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[ 44708.555] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 44708.555]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 0.4.4
[ 44708.555]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 44708.555]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[ 44708.555] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[ 44708.555] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[ 44708.555] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 44708.555]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.3.3
[ 44708.555]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 44708.555]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[ 44708.555] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[ 44708.555] (II) RADEON: Driver for ATI Radeon chipsets:
[ 44708.560] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[ 44708.560] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[ 44708.560] (--) using VT number 7

[ 44708.578] (II) modesetting(0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[ 44708.578] (II) modesetting(G0): using drv /dev/dri/card1
[ 44708.578] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[ 44708.578] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[ 44708.578] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[ 44708.578] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[ 44708.578] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 44708.578]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 0.0.2
[ 44708.578]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 15.0
[ 44708.578] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[ 44708.578] (**) modesetting(0): Depth 16, (--) framebuffer bpp 16
[ 44708.578] (==) modesetting(0): RGB weight 565
[ 44708.578] (==) modesetting(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[ 44708.578] (II) modesetting(0): ShadowFB: preferred YES, enabled YES
[ 44708.608] (II) modesetting(0): Output VGA-0 using monitor section DisplayLinkMonitor
[ 44708.610] (II) modesetting(0): Output DVI-0 has no monitor section
[ 44708.640] (II) modesetting(0): EDID for output VGA-0
[ 44708.640] (II) modesetting(0): Manufacturer: ACR  Model: 74  Serial#: 2483090993
[ 44708.640] (II) modesetting(0): Year: 2009  Week: 40
[ 44708.640] (II) modesetting(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[ 44708.640] (II) modesetting(0): Analog Display Input,  Input Voltage Level: 0.700/0.700 V
[ 44708.640] (II) modesetting(0): Sync:  Separate
[ 44708.640] (II) modesetting(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 53  vert.: 29
[ 44708.640] (II) modesetting(0): Gamma: 2.20
[ 44708.640] (II) modesetting(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off; RGB/Color Display
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): redX: 0.649 redY: 0.338   greenX: 0.289 greenY: 0.609
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): blueX: 0.146 blueY: 0.070   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): Supported established timings:
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): 720x400@70Hz
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): 640x480@60Hz
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): 640x480@72Hz
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): 640x480@75Hz
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): 800x600@56Hz
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): 800x600@60Hz
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): 800x600@72Hz
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): 800x600@75Hz
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): 1024x768@60Hz
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): 1024x768@70Hz
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): 1024x768@75Hz
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): 1280x1024@75Hz
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): Supported standard timings:
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): #0: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): #1: hsize: 1152  vsize 864  refresh: 75  vid: 20337
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): #2: hsize: 1440  vsize 900  refresh: 60  vid: 149
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): #3: hsize: 1440  vsize 900  refresh: 75  vid: 3989
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): #4: hsize: 1600  vsize 1200  refresh: 60  vid: 16553
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): #5: hsize: 1680  vsize 1050  refresh: 60  vid: 179
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): Supported detailed timing:
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): clock: 138.5 MHz   Image Size:  531 x 298 mm
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): h_active: 1920  h_sync: 1968  h_sync_end 2000 h_blank_end 2080 h_border: 0
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): v_active: 1080  v_sync: 1083  v_sync_end 1088 v_blanking: 1111 v_border: 0
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): Monitor name: H243H
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): Ranges: V min: 56 V max: 76 Hz, H min: 31 H max: 83 kHz, PixClock max 185 MHz
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): Serial No: LEW0C0044002
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0): EDID (in hex):
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0):   00ffffffffffff000472740031f60094
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0):   2813010368351d78ea6085a6564a9c25
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0):   125054afcf008180714f9500950fa940
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0):   b300010101011a3680a070381f403020
[ 44708.641] (II) modesetting(0):   3500132a2100001a000000fc00483234
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0):   33480a20202020202020000000fd0038
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0):   4c1f5312000a202020202020000000ff
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0):   004c45573043303034343030320a003c
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Printing probed modes for output VGA-0
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz UeP)
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x59.9  138.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync (66.6 kHz eP)
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x60.0  162.00  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz e)
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x60.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Modeline "1440x900"x75.0  136.75  1440 1536 1688 1936  900 903 909 942 -hsync +vsync (70.6 kHz e)
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Modeline "1440x900"x59.9  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Modeline "1152x864"x75.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Modeline "1024x768"x75.1   78.80  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.1 kHz e)
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Modeline "1024x768"x70.1   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Modeline "800x600"x72.2   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Modeline "800x600"x75.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Modeline "800x600"x56.2   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Modeline "640x480"x75.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Modeline "640x480"x72.8   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 491 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Modeline "640x480"x60.0   25.20  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[ 44708.642] (II) modesetting(0): Modeline "720x400"x70.1   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[ 44708.645] (II) modesetting(0): EDID for output DVI-0
[ 44708.645] (II) modesetting(0): Output VGA-0 connected
[ 44708.645] (II) modesetting(0): Output DVI-0 disconnected
[ 44708.645] (II) modesetting(0): Using user preference for initial modes
[ 44708.645] (II) modesetting(0): Output VGA-0 using initial mode 1280x1024
[ 44708.645] (II) modesetting(0): Using default gamma of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) unless otherwise stated.
[ 44708.645] (==) modesetting(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[ 44708.645] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[ 44708.645] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[ 44708.645] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[ 44708.645] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 44708.645]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[ 44708.645]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[ 44708.645] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[ 44708.645] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[ 44708.646] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[ 44708.646] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 44708.646]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.1.0
[ 44708.646]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[ 44708.646] (**) modesetting(G0): Depth 16, (--) framebuffer bpp 16
[ 44708.646] (==) modesetting(G0): RGB weight 565
[ 44708.646] (==) modesetting(G0): Default visual is TrueColor
[ 44708.646] (II) modesetting(G0): ShadowFB: preferred NO, enabled NO
[ 44708.727] (II) modesetting(G0): Output DVI-1-0 using monitor section DisplayLinkMonitor
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID for output DVI-1-0
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): Manufacturer: WDE  Model: 1702  Serial#: 0
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): Year: 2005  Week: 14
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID Version: 1.3
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): Analog Display Input,  Input Voltage Level: 0.700/0.700 V
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): Sync:  Separate
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 34  vert.: 27
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): Gamma: 2.20
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off; RGB/Color Display
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): Default color space is primary color space
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): GTF timings supported
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): redX: 0.643 redY: 0.352   greenX: 0.283 greenY: 0.608
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): blueX: 0.147 blueY: 0.102   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): Supported established timings:
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): 720x400@70Hz
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): 640x480@60Hz
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): 640x480@67Hz
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): 640x480@72Hz
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): 640x480@75Hz
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): 800x600@56Hz
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): 800x600@60Hz
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): 800x600@72Hz
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): 800x600@75Hz
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): 832x624@75Hz
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): 1024x768@60Hz
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): 1024x768@70Hz
[ 44708.808] (II) modesetting(G0): 1024x768@75Hz
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): 1280x1024@75Hz
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): Supported standard timings:
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): #0: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): #1: hsize: 1152  vsize 864  refresh: 75  vid: 20337
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): Supported detailed timing:
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): clock: 108.0 MHz   Image Size:  338 x 270 mm
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): h_active: 1280  h_sync: 1328  h_sync_end 1440 h_blank_end 1688 h_border: 0
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): v_active: 1024  v_sync: 1025  v_sync_end 1028 v_blanking: 1066 v_border: 0
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): Ranges: V min: 50 V max: 75 Hz, H min: 30 H max: 82 kHz, PixClock max 145 MHz
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): Monitor name: WDE LCM-17v2
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): Serial No: 0
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): EDID (in hex):
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0):  00ffffffffffff005c85021700000000
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0):  0e0f010368221b78ef8bc5a45a489b25
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0):  1a5054bfef008180714f010101010101
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0):  010101010101302a009851002a403070
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0):  1300520e1100001e000000fd00324b1e
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0):  520e000a202020202020000000fc0057
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0):  4445204c434d2d313776320a000000ff
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0):  00300a202020202020202020202000e7
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): Printing probed modes for output DVI-1-0
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz UeP)
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1280x1024"x75.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1280x960"x60.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1280x800"x74.9  106.50  1280 1360 1488 1696  800 803 809 838 -hsync +vsync (62.8 kHz e)
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1280x800"x59.8   83.50  1280 1352 1480 1680  800 803 809 831 +hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1152x864"x75.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1280x768"x74.9  102.25  1280 1360 1488 1696  768 771 778 805 +hsync -vsync (60.3 kHz e)
[ 44708.809] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1280x768"x59.9   79.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  768 771 778 798 -hsync +vsync (47.8 kHz e)
[ 44708.810] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1024x768"x75.1   78.80  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.1 kHz e)
[ 44708.810] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1024x768"x70.1   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
[ 44708.810] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[ 44708.810] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "1024x576"x60.0   46.97  1024 1064 1168 1312  576 577 580 597 -hsync +vsync (35.8 kHz)
[ 44708.810] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "832x624"x74.6   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
[ 44708.810] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "800x600"x72.2   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
[ 44708.810] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "800x600"x75.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[ 44708.810] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[ 44708.810] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "800x600"x56.2   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
[ 44708.810] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "848x480"x60.0   33.75  848 864 976 1088  480 486 494 517 +hsync +vsync (31.0 kHz e)
[ 44708.810] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "640x480"x75.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[ 44708.810] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "640x480"x72.8   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 491 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[ 44708.810] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "640x480"x66.7   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[ 44708.810] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "640x480"x60.0   25.20  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[ 44708.810] (II) modesetting(G0): Modeline "720x400"x70.1   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[ 44708.810] (II) modesetting(G0): Using default gamma of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) unless otherwise stated.
[ 44708.810] (==) modesetting(G0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[ 44708.810] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[ 44708.810] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[ 44708.810] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[ 44708.810] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 44708.810]    compiled for 1.15.1, module version = 1.0.0
[ 44708.811]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[ 44708.811] (II) UnloadModule: "radeon"
[ 44708.811] (II) Unloading radeon
[ 44708.811] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[ 44708.811] (II) Unloading fbdev
[ 44708.811] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[ 44708.811] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[ 44708.811] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[ 44708.811] (II) Unloading vesa
[ 44708.811] (==) modesetting(G0): Backing store enabled
[ 44708.811] (==) modesetting(G0): Silken mouse enabled
[ 44708.812] (II) modesetting(G0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[ 44708.812] (==) modesetting(G0): DPMS enabled
[ 44708.812] (WW) modesetting(G0): Option "fbdev" is not used
[ 44708.812] (==) modesetting(0): Backing store enabled
[ 44708.812] (==) modesetting(0): Silken mouse enabled
[ 44708.812] (II) modesetting(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[ 44708.812] (==) modesetting(0): DPMS enabled
[ 44708.812] (WW) modesetting(0): Option "fbdev" is not used
[ 44708.856] (--) RandR disabled
[ 44708.867] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[ 44708.868] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[ 44708.868] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[ 44708.878] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[ 44708.878] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[ 44708.879] (II) modesetting(G0): Damage tracking initialized
[ 44708.879] (II) modesetting(0): Damage tracking initialized
[ 44708.879] (II) modesetting(0): Setting screen physical size to 338 x 270
[ 44708.900] (II) XKB: generating xkmfile /tmp/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[ 44708.918] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[ 44708.918] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[ 44708.918] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[ 44708.918] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[ 44708.918] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 44708.918]    compiled for 1.15.0, module version = 2.8.2
[ 44708.918]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[ 44708.918]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 20.0
[ 44708.918] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[ 44708.918] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[ 44708.918] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[ 44708.918] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[ 44708.918] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[ 44708.918] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[ 44708.918] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1/event1"
[ 44708.918] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[ 44708.918] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[ 44708.918] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[ 44708.918] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 44708.919] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[ 44708.919] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[ 44708.919] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[ 44708.919] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[ 44708.919] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[ 44708.919] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[ 44708.919] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[ 44708.919] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[ 44708.919] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this problem.

Comment: how about dmesg? anything about nommu_map_sg: overflow 110db4000+45056 of device mask ffffffff thats what mine does ...i have 2 installs of 14.04, one is a fresh upgrade and the other is older ... the older upgrade (these are exact clones of 13.10, ) that iv been using - the displaylink works if i leave it unplugged till the request to login ...plug in and continue login ... once at desktop i can set display settings and turn on the display (under the Display controls) and it works ... My more recent upgrade recognizes the DL-165 but i never get anything on the display and thats the only error